# git clone all git repositories present in bitbucket with the help of intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I am not sure if it is possible with Intellij but is it possible to clone and manage all git repo present in bitbucket project easily with Intellij. I have seen few examples with python, shell script, but I don't want to go ahead with this approach

Comment: have you check their documentation? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html

Comment: Why dont you just write a script outside of intellij to clone all the repo's you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clone all repositories from your bitbucket account with a single command - then no, it is not possible. TBH, the use case for this is also not clear.

Currently, you can clone a single repository by its URL. There is also [Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) that adds an icon to the Bitbucket Web UI to allow a [single-click clone](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2019/10/22/toolbox-app-1-16-open-files-from-github-gitlab-bitbucket/)

From within the IDE, there is no integration with Bitbucket account yet, so there is no any completion or repo list - see/vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88198